# How can I get the next/previous numbers from the given number x in ieee754 format?

Tags: javascript, precision, ieee-754

If x is an integer, it is easy to get the next number of given x.

```
int x = 100;
x++; // There are no integers between 100 and 101.
```

What kind of operation should I proceed to get the next value of IEEE754 formatted values, mostly used in JavaScript?

```
var x = Math.PI;
var nextX = f(x);
// I don't know what value nextX will be, but I want it to be sure that
// there are no numbers existing between x and nextX in IEEE754 format.
```

How about the previous number?

Comment: The IEEE754 spec calls that function `nextUp(n)` - it's not implemented in the JavaScript `Math` collection, but [at least one person has worked on a reasonably efficient implementation](https://gist.github.com/Yaffle/4654250).